# Don't allow to select other option if selected specific value with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

As you can see i have select box with the select2 (multiple) select feature, with some option like

```
<option value="All"> All </option>
<option value="test@email.com"> User 1</option>
<option value="test2@email.com"> User 2 </option>
<option value="Test3@rmail.com"> User 3 </option>
```

is that possible that if i choose the option `All` from the select box then select box dose't not allow me to choose the other option from the given options until and unless i remove it.

I want to restrict the user to select either choose `All`  or select the multiple users from the options.

i am ready to use jQuery or javascript to achieve this.

Comment: try the html `disabled` attribute.

Comment: naah , i dont wanna disable, If he selected All first , then after he try to select the user then All should be removed and selected option should be selected with the allowing multiple feature

Comment: You think you can actually do this with just HTML? I say again, disable all other options when selecting `all`, when reselecting remove the disabled attribute oh and, yes you need javascript for this.

Comment: @Xorifelse i am ready to use jQuery or javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/fyhsz9ra/815/)**.

You could set the value of select to All when the option `All` is presented :

```
$("#my-select").select2();

$("#my-select").on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();

    if(selected != null)
    {
      if(selected.indexOf('All')>=0){
          $(this).val('All').select2();
      }
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#my-select").select2();

$("#my-select").on('change', function(){
  var selected = $(this).val();

  if(selected != null)
  {
    if(selected.indexOf('All')>=0){
      $(this).val('All').select2();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select multiple id="my-select" style="width:300px">
  <option value="All"> All </option>
  <option value="test@email.com"> User 1</option>
  <option value="test2@email.com"> User 2 </option>
  <option value="Test3@rmail.com"> User 3 </option>
</select>
```